# python. Unable to run program

Tags: python

I'm new to Python programming. 
I was trying to achieve the following output:

```
Account c
Account count = 1
Successful transaction! Balance = 10000
Successful transaction! Balance = 9000
Not enough balance
```

My code:

```
class Account:
    accountCount = 0
    def __init__(self, name, accountNo):
        self.name = name
        self.accountNo = accountNo
        self.balance = 0
        Account.accountCount += 1
        print ("Account " + self.accountNo)
        print ("Account count= " +str(Account.accountCount))

    def withdraw (self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount
        return self.balance

    def deposit (self,amount):
        self.balance += amount
        return self.balance

    myAccount = Account ("c", "c123")
    myAccount.deposit(10000)
    myAccount.withdraw(500)
    myAccount.withdraw(10000)
```

I get the following error

```
line 1, in <module>
line 20, in Account myAccount = Account ("c", "c123")
NameError: name 'Account' is not defined
```

Comment: Fix your indentation, your code works. The last 4 lines should be outside the class block, should be 1 indent back. And `_str_()` should be `__str__()` or better `str(Account.accountCount)`

Comment: or use `str(Account.accountCount)` instead

Comment: I've made the changes but I still get the same error

Comment: Take out the last 4 lines out of class block. They should be at the same level of class.

Comment: @iridescent Add the desired print statements and additional logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with indentation. Moving your code logic to the beginning of the line will execute your code.

```
class Account:
    accountCount = 0

    def __init__(self, name, accountNo):
        self.name = name
        self.accountNo = accountNo
        self.balance = 0
        Account.accountCount += 1
        print("Account " + self.accountNo)
        print("Account count = " + str(Account.accountCount))

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount
        return self.balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
        return self.balance


account_c = Account("c", "c123")
account_c.deposit(10000)
account_c.withdraw(500)
account_c.withdraw(10000)
```

Output:

```
Account c123
Account count = 1
```